# How to change the popup window's score to a percentage?

Tags: javascript, testing, dreamweaver, popupwindow, onsubmit

I am trying to create a basic IQ Test with JavaScript, containing only 6 questions.

If you get all questions right and after you click submit, the automatic pop up window will give you a score of 6. However I want it to show a percentage based on the number of correct answers.

Here's what I've tried (you'll see that my problem probably is in the variables):

```
function calculate()
{
    var x, y, score;
    y;

    x = document.personalinfo.firstname.value;

    score = (y*100)/6;
    window.alert("Hey " + x + ", your score is: " + score);

    if(document.IQTest.Q1[0,1,3,4].checked == true)
        score++;

    if(document.IQTest.Q2[2].checked == true)
        score++;

    if(document.IQTest.Q3[1].checked == true)
        score++;

    if(document.IQTest.Q4[3].checked == true)
        score++;

    if(document.IQTest.Q5[2].checked == true)
        score++;

    if(document.IQTest.Q6[0,2,4].checked == true)
        score++;
}
```

Comment: `score / 6 * 100`?

Comment: Why are you displaying the score before you check the answers? And where do you set `y`?

Comment: What do you think  `document.IQTest.Q1[0,1,3,4].checked == true` means? FYI, it's equivalent to `document.IQTest.Q1[4].checked == true` -- read about the Javascript [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Comment: But it doesn't mean to test if any or all of those checkboxes is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just that the code's a bit out of order and you mixed up two variables.

```
function calculate() {
var x, y, score;

score = 0;
x = document.personalinfo.firstname.value;

if(document.IQTest.Q1[0,1,3,4].checked == true) score++;
if(document.IQTest.Q2[2].checked == true) score++;
if(document.IQTest.Q3[1].checked == true) score++;
if(document.IQTest.Q4[3].checked == true) score++;
if(document.IQTest.Q5[2].checked == true) score++;
if(document.IQTest.Q6[0,2,4].checked == true) score++;

y = (score*100)/6;

window.alert("Hey " + x + ", your score is: " + y);
}
```

Comment: As a side note, just for better clarity in your code, I would rewrite `(score*100)/6` as `(score/6)*100`. The ` == true` is also redundant in your conditionals (you can remove it).

Comment: As a side note, I would always enclose branches of `if` statements in `{` and `}` to avoid bugs later.

Comment: @MarionX.Koumoutopoulou Initialize `score`, maybe? (See updated answer.)

Comment: hey thanks for the quick reply! unfortunately, it doesnt work. So.. x=user's name [input], y=the score or number of correct questions given by the popup window [ranging from 0 to 6 as I have only 6 questions in my test] and score=(y*100)/6 [which score as you can see need to be a percentage..] I'm clarifying these again as i think my description above wasnt very illuminating

Comment: the problem seems to be with the y variably, which is given by the pop up window

Comment: @MarionX.Koumoutopoulou The pop-up shows the number right instead of a percentage?

Comment: yeap. if i have 5 questions right it will give me "hey your score is 5", if i have 4 it will show me 4 and so on..

Comment: @MarionX.Koumoutopoulou My mistake. I updated the answer.

Comment: You need to fix things like `Q1[0,1,3,4]`, it almost certainly doesn't do what the OP wants.

Comment: @Barmar not sure what you mean. With q1[0,1,3,4] I refer to a question with checkboxes, where more than one answer is possible. The corrected code takes into consideration the multiple correct answers and gives the result in percentage as i wanted

Comment: @MarionX.Koumoutopoulou Putting a list of indexes in square brackets doesn't mean to use all of those elements, it just refers to the last index `4`. See my link above to the comma operator.